# React Dropzone issue : children is not a function

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dropzone

I've installed react dropzone in a react app. When adding the component dropzone, the app crashes, claiming that:

```
TypeError: children is not a function
Dropzone.render
node_modules/react-dropzone/dist/es/index.js:478
475 | var isMultipleAllowed = multiple || filesCount <= 1;
476 | var isDragAccept = filesCount > 0 && 
allFilesAccepted(draggedFiles, this.props.accept);
477 | var isDragReject = filesCount > 0 && (!isDragAccept ||!isMultipleAllowed);
> 478 | return children({
  | ^  479 |   isDragActive: isDragActive,
480 |   isDragAccept: isDragAccept,
481 |   isDragReject: isDragReject,
```

Yet, everything seems fine. My App.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DropImg from './components/DropImg.js';

class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
   <DropImg />
  </div>
)}}
export default App;
```

and the component DropImg is:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone"

class DropImg extends Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Drop your file</h1>
            <Dropzone>Drop file here</Dropzone>
        </div>
    )}}

export default DropImg;
```

There are no functions to handle drag & whatnot. Just a very basic set up. Yet it crashes. Why? The issue seems to come from the react-dropzone package itself.

ps: I've read the documentation, but it was not crystal clear. It is the first time I'm implementing such a feature, could you please explain to me how to fix this issue in a simple manner? Thanks!

Comment: check your isDragActive state

Answer (score 14):

As the error message says, `Dropzone` is expecting a render function but you didn't provide it.

> The render property function is what you use to render whatever you
>   want to based on the state of `Dropzone`.

You can try it like this.

```
<Dropzone>
  {dropzoneProps => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Drop some files here</p>
      </div>
    );
  }}
</Dropzone>;
```